# (Identifier) terms vs. constants vs. null signature routines

Tags: raku

Identifier terms are defined in the documentation [alongside constants](https://docs.raku.org/language/terms#Identifier_terms), with pretty much the same use case, although terms compute their value in run time while constants get it in compile time. Potentially, that could make terms use global variables, but that's action at a distance and ugly, so I guess that's not their use case.
OTOH, they could be simply routines with null signature:

```
sub term:<þor> { "Is mighty" }
sub Þor { "Is mighty" }

say þor, Þor;
```

But you can already define routines with null signature. You can sabe, however, the error when you write:

```
say Þor ~ Þor;
```

Which would [produce a `many positionals passed; expected 0 arguments but got 1`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/term:%3C%3E), unlike the term. That seems however a bit farfetched and you can save the trouble by just adding () at the end.

Another possible use case is [*defying the rules of normal identifiers*](https://docs.raku.org/routine/term:%3C%3E)

```
sub term:<✔> { True }
say ✔; # True
```

Are there any other use cases I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants are basically terms. So of course they are grouped together.

```perl6
constant foo = 12;

say foo;

constant term:<bar> = 36;

say bar;
```

There is a slight difference because `term:<…>` works by modifying the parser. So it takes precedence.

```perl6
constant fubar = 38;
constant term:<fubar> = 45;

say fubar; # 45
```

The above will print `45` regardless of which `constant` definition comes first.

Since `term:<…>` takes precedence the only way to get at the other value is to use `::<fubar>` to directly access the symbol table.

```perl6
say ::<fubar>; # 38
say ::<term:<fubar>>; # 45
```

---

There are two main use-cases for `term:<…>`.

One is to get a subroutine to be parsed similarly to a constant or sigilless variable.

```perl6
sub fubar () { 'fubar'.comb.roll }

# say( fubar( prefix:<~>( 4 ) ) );
say fubar ~ 4; # ERROR
```

```perl6
sub term:<fubar> () { 'fubar'.comb.roll }

# say( infix:<~>( fubar, 4 ) );
say fubar ~ 4;
```

The other is to have a constant or sigiless variable be something other than an a normal identifier.

```perl6
my \✔ = True; # ERROR: Malformed my
```

```perl6
my \term:<✔> = True;

say ✔;
```

Of course both use-cases can be combined.

```perl6
sub term:<✔> () { True }
```

---

Perl 5 allows subroutines to have an empty prototype (different than a signature) which will alter how it gets parsed. The main purpose of prototypes in Perl 5 is to alter how the code gets parsed.

```perl
use v5;

sub fubar () { ord [split('','fubar')]->[rand 5] }

# say( fubar() + 4 );
say fubar + 4; # infix +
```

```perl
use v5;

sub fubar { ord [split('','fubar')]->[rand 5] }

# say( fubar( +4 ) );
say fubar + 4; # prefix +
```

Perl 6 doesn't use signatures the way Perl 5 uses prototypes. The main way to alter how Perl 6 parses code is by using the namespace.

```perl6
use v6;

sub fubar ( $_ ) { .comb.roll }
sub term:<fubar> () { 'fubar'.comb.roll }

say fubar( 'zoo' ); # `z` or `o` (`o` is twice as likely)
say fubar; # `f` or `u` or `b` or `a` or `r`


sub prefix:<✔> ( $_ ) { "checked $_" }

say ✔ 'under the bed'; # checked under the bed
```

Note that Perl 5 doesn't really have constants, they are just subroutines with an empty prototype.

```perl
use v5;

use constant foo => 12;
```

```perl
use v5;

sub foo () { 12 } # ditto
```

(This became less true after 5.16)

---

As far as I know all of the other uses of prototypes have been superseded by design decisions in Perl 6.

```perl
use v5;
sub foo (&$) { $_[0]->($_[1]) }

say foo { 100 + $_[0] } 5; # 105;
```

That block is seen as a `sub` lambda because of the prototype of the `foo` subroutine.

```perl6
use v6;
# sub foo ( &f, $v ) { f $v }
sub foo { @_[0].( @_[1] ) }

say foo { 100 + @_[0] }, 5; # 105
```

In Perl 6 a block is seen as a lambda if a term is expected. So there is no need to alter the parser with a feature like a prototype.

---

You are asking for exactly one use of prototypes to be brought back even though there is already a feature that covers that use-case.

Doing so would be a special-case. Part of the design ethos of Perl 6 is to limit the number of special-cases.
Other versions of Perl had a wide variety of special-cases, and it isn't always easy to remember them all.

Don't get me wrong; the special-cases in Perl 5 are useful, but Perl 6 has for the most part made them general-cases.

Answer (score 5):

Making zero-argument subs work as terms will break the possibility to post-declare subs, since finding a sub after having parsed usages of it would require re-parsing of earlier code (which the perl 6 language refuses to do, "one-pass parsing" and all that) if the sub takes no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Terms are useful in combination with the ternary operator:

```
$ perl6 -e 'sub a() { "foo" }; say 42 ?? a !! 666'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Your !! was gobbled by the expression in the middle; please parenthesize

$ perl6 -e 'sub term:<a> { "foo" }; say 42 ?? a !! 666'
foo
```